# Extend colorscheme with custom matches

Tags: vim

My colourscheme (Tomorrow Night) exposes the following colours variables:

```
" Default GUI Colours
let s:foreground = "c5c8c6"
let s:background = "1d1f21"
let s:selection = "373b41"
let s:line = "282a2e"
let s:comment = "969896"
let s:red = "cc6666"
let s:orange = "de935f"
let s:yellow = "f0c674"
let s:green = "b5bd68"
let s:aqua = "8abeb7"
let s:blue = "81a2be"
let s:purple = "b294bb"
let s:window = "4d5057"
```

I'm looking forward to create new matches and highlight groups reusing those colours.

For example, I'm trying to highlight my own `LESSVariable` group with `s:red`, and I tried:

```
hi LESSVariable guifg=s:red
call <SID>X("LESSVariable", s:red, "", "")
```

In conjunction with my match rule:

```
match LESSVariable /@[\w_-]+/
```

From the `let` keywords in the variables above I can deduce that those variables are only visible within the theme file.

What can I do to accomplish this?

If not possible using the `s:red` variable directly, can I tell Vim somehow that my `LESSVariable` group should look like group X (for example, like `rubyConstant`)?

**EDIT:** Tomorrow Night translates the gui hexadecimals to cterm colours for Terminal support. If possible, I'd like to support both GUI and Terminal in my customisations.

Answer (score 0):

- The easy way.

  Instead of creating your own highlight group, use one that's already defined by your colorscheme and looks just like you want. For example:

  ```
  call <SID>X("WarningMsg", s:red, "", "")
  call <SID>X("Identifier", s:red, "", "none")
  call <SID>X("vimCommand", s:red, "", "none")
  etc…
  ```
- The other easy way.

  Add your highlight group to the colorscheme.
- Another easy way.

  Use [an existing less syntax script](https://github.com/groenewege/vim-less) that already has what you want.